# Multiprocessing child task continues to leak more memory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I have a large delimited file. I need to apply a function to each line in this file where each function call takes a while. So I have sharded the main file into subfiles like `<shard-dir>/lines_<start>_<stop>.tsv` and 
am applying a function via `pool.starmap` to each file. Since I want to also maintain the results, I am writing the results as they come to a corresponding output file: `<output-shard-dir>/lines_<start>_<stop>_results.tsv`.

The function I am mapping looks something like:

```py
# this is pseudo-code, but similar to what I am using
def process_shard_file(file):
    output_file = output_filename_from_shard_filename(file)
    with open(file, 'r') as fi, open(output_file, 'w') as fo:
        result = heavy_computation_function(fi.readline())
        fo.write(stringify(result))
```

the multiprocessing is then started via something like:

```py
shard_files = [...] # a lot of filenames

with Pool(processes=os.cpu_count()) as pool:
    sargs = [(fname,) for fname in shard_files]
    pool.starmap(process_shard_file, sargs)
```

when monitoring my computer's resources with `htop` I see that all cores are full throttle, fine. However, I notice that the memory usage just keeps increasing, and increasing, until it hits swap... and then until swap is also full.

I do not understand why this is happening as several files (`n * cpu_cores`) from `process_shard_file` are completed successfully.  So why isn't the memory stable? Assuming that `heavy_computation_function` uses essentially equal memory regardless of file and `result` is also equally sized

#### Update

```py
def process_shard_file(file):
    output_file = output_filename_from_shard_filename(file)
    with open(file, 'r') as fi, open(output_file, 'w') as fo:
        result = fi.readline()# heavy_computation_function(fi.readline())
        fo.write(result)
```

above does not seem to cause this issue of memory leakage, where `result` from
`heavy_computation_function` can be thought of basically another line to be written to the output file.

So what does `heavy_computation_function` look like?

```py
def heavy_computation_function(fileline):
    numba_input = convert_line_to_numba_input(fileline)
    result = cached_njitted_function(numba_input)
    return convert_to_more_friendly_format(result)
```

I know this is still fairly vague, but I am trying to see if this is a generalized problem or not. I have also tried adding the option of `maxtasksperchild=1` to my `Pool` to really try and prevent leakage to no avail.

Comment: What does the `shard_files` list look like?

Comment: @ForceBru a list of strings, where each string is the full path to a shard file. A shard file is `n` lines of the original large file

Comment: This code shouldn't work then. `starmap` would try to call `process_shard_file(*'/full/path/to/file')` for each path, thus trying to pass 18 (!) arguments to the function `process_shard_file(file)`, which accepts only one argument.

Comment: @ForceBru assume that the code works, as it does. In this case I was just free typing and trying to reduce what I have to a mwe. In this case it should actually be a list of tuples of only one element containing the filename.

Comment: As [the docs for `multiprocessing.map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) say, "it may cause _high memory usage_ for very long iterables". It's recommended to use `imap` or `imap_unordered` instead.

Comment: @ForceBru so how would that work for starmap

Comment: If `process_shard_file` takes only one argument, you can use `imap` with a list of strings (and not a list of tuples), for example.

Comment: @ForceBru it was simplified for the example, it takes some `args` and `kwargs`

Comment: I guess all these codes are just irrelevant. There might be somewhere in your `process_shard_file` function which creates some leaking objects every time but you just didn't notice. I've also done something similar through 4 million files without any issue. So how about double checking your program carefully?

Comment: @Sraw while the above code is not 1-to-1 exact with my own, it is closely representative. `heavy_computation_function` is a `njit`-ed `numba` function. It is put into a variable, and then string-ified to a file. So if the leak is in `process_shard_file` I do not know what it would be.

Comment: How about you call it multiple times just in the main process to see if memory still goes out of bound. If it does, then clearly that there is some leakage in your function instead of related to `multiprocessing`.

Comment: @Sraw I tried commenting out the `heavy_computation_function` and replacing it with just the reading of the line from the input file, in hopes to see if it was the variable `result`  that was causing the leakage, since the output is about the same size and structure. This was not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Your program works, but only for a little while
before self-destructing due to resource leakage.
One could choose to accept such un-diagnosed leakage
as a fact of life that won't change today.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) points out that sometimes Leaks Happen,
and offers a *maxtasksperchild* parameter to help deal with it.
Set it high enough so you benefit from amortizing initial startup
cost over several tasks, but low enough to avoid swapping.
Let us know how it works out for you.

Comment: should I try manually calling garbage collection then? of could I for-loop over the `starmap`, sending out only `n` processes at a time, so that `starmap` can properly resolve?

Comment: (1.) You were a bit vague about the `heavy_computation_function()`. Either it's pure python, or it also involves a C extension. It is clear that it leaks memory which is only reclaimed when the process exits, which is what a finite _maxtasksperchild_ will cause. A C extension might have its own tunable GC. For python, you can't magically GC buggy code and expect memory use to decrease. The cPython interpreter is already ref-counting correctly. You might need to assign `some_dict = None` or similar, to let it collect. (2.) You were a bit vague about the magnitude of `n`. Reducing it would help.

Comment: in short each line of the sharded file stores arguments for `heavy_computation_function`, which does some computation and returns a set of values. `numba` compiles the decorated python with `llvm` so it should be c. I can check with those guys if they might have leakage. At the moment I have 40 cores and 1.2M lines, split into files of 200 lines. I make it to 200K lines before out of RAM / swap (100GB). So I could make `n=120`  so that each process handles 3 shared files before completing, then taking the next 120.

Comment: Sounds like you want to put together a single-threaded Repeat-By: that demonstrates python repeatedly calling the `@njit` function where memory use grows without bound. After each call monitor `getrusage(ru.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss` and note whether it ever plateaus. Start with a small function, which doesn't leak, and keep adding things until it shows broken behavior.

Comment: does it matter that I cached the njit function?

Comment: Nah, I can't imagine that caching a function would hurt you.

Comment: tried `maxtasksperchild=1` and leaks keep happening :( waiting to hear from numba